# Selectively filter rows where column value is not null PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-order-by, greatest-n-per-group, sql-null

I have following table in Postgres 11.0.

```
col1        col2        col3                                                       col4             col5
1           NCT02582996 acetaminophen+caffeine+dihydroergotamine+metoclopramide.    metoclopramide. 204756
1           NCT02582996 acetaminophen+caffeine+dihydroergotamine+metoclopramide.    metoclopramide. null
3           NCT02582997 acetaminophen                                               metoclopramide. 204758
4           NCT02582998 ibuprufin                                                   ibuprufin       null
```

For same col1 value, I would like to keep only those rows where col5 is not null. and discard the other row.

Desired output is:

```
col1        col2        col3                                                       col4             col5
1           NCT02582996 acetaminophen+caffeine+dihydroergotamine+metoclopramide.    metoclopramide. 204756
3           NCT02582997 acetaminophen                                               metoclopramide. 204758
4           NCT02582998 ibuprufin                                                   ibuprufin       null
```

```
select * from tbl where col5 is not null  --excluding row 4
```

I am not sure how can I achieve this. Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Do just want to **SELECT** the rows, or actually **DELETE** the non-needed rows?

Comment: I would prefer to select them.

Comment: Then: your query does what you want.

Comment: will it include:    4           NCT02582998    ibuprufin       ibuprufin       null

Comment: Why do you want to retain record 4?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can use use `distinct on`:

```
select distinct on (col1) t.*
from tbl t
order by col1, col5
```

This generates one row per distinct value in `col1` only. If `col1` has both a non-`null` and `null` value in `col5`, then the non-`null` value is preserved. If there is only one row available, with a `null` value, then it is selected.

Comment: To be explicit about the logic, you could use `order by col1, col5 nulls last`.

Comment: Personally I think that DISTINCT (ON) is a bad habit, it is like corticosteroids for queries.

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE TABLE tbl
        ( col1 integer
        , col2 text
        , col3 text
        , col4 text
        , col5 integer
        );
INSERT INTO tbl
VALUES
(1, 'NCT02582996', 'acetaminophen+caffeine+dihydroergotamine+metoclopramide.', 'metoclopramide.', 204756)
,(1, 'NCT02582996','acetaminophen+caffeine+dihydroergotamine+metoclopramide.', 'metoclopramide.',NULL)
,(3, 'NCT02582997','acetaminophen', 'metoclopramide.', 204758)
,(4, 'NCT02582998','ibuprufin',NULL,NULL)
        ;

select * from tbl t1;

select * from tbl t1
where col5 is not null
OR NOT EXISTS (
        select * from tbl x
        WHERE x.col1 = t1.col1
        and x.col5 is not null
        );
```

---

Results:

---

```
CREATE TABLE
INSERT 0 4
 col1 |    col2     |                           col3                           |      col4       |  col5  
------+-------------+----------------------------------------------------------+-----------------+--------
    1 | NCT02582996 | acetaminophen+caffeine+dihydroergotamine+metoclopramide. | metoclopramide. | 204756
    1 | NCT02582996 | acetaminophen+caffeine+dihydroergotamine+metoclopramide. | metoclopramide. |       
    3 | NCT02582997 | acetaminophen                                            | metoclopramide. | 204758
    4 | NCT02582998 | ibuprufin                                                |                 |       
(4 rows)

 col1 |    col2     |                           col3                           |      col4       |  col5  
------+-------------+----------------------------------------------------------+-----------------+--------
    1 | NCT02582996 | acetaminophen+caffeine+dihydroergotamine+metoclopramide. | metoclopramide. | 204756
    3 | NCT02582997 | acetaminophen                                            | metoclopramide. | 204758
    4 | NCT02582998 | ibuprufin                                                |                 |       
(3 rows)
```